# dll hijacking, replacing dll in folder

Tags: dll

i'm trying to understand how dll hijacking works practically for educational purpose.
I also try to fund some countermeasure as i'm currently programming a software with a friend that contains dll and an executable in a archive.
Currently the best solution i found is to check checksum of dll loaded. Are there better solution ? I want avoid solution like check EV certificat etc...

According the exploitation of dll hijacking if i understand well, the attacker just need to replace the dll by a malicious dll that as malicious code that is executed in entrypoint ?

I have created a dll with messagebox code in c, and i have created a buggy code (executable) to make a proof of concept. This worked fine.  (here the image : https://ibb.co/GpDF3sP)
But when i try test it with true software on market this doesn't work. (https://ibb.co/PDLxF59 and https://ibb.co/QJP4Hxj dll is not loaded after i changed it) Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Attacker must create same DLL export table as in your DLL. Then he just load your original DLL module in fake one and pass all calls to it, so attacker's DLL will be used like a proxy for each call.
Honestly, if you're loading DLL statically with Windows PE loader, checksum and certificate are not so reliable methods. For example, if I have access to filesystem for write, I can replace your original DLL with fake one, start your process in suspended state, replace DLL to original behind your EXE module, resume your process execution (file moving operation is available even DLL file is using). And you can check DLL checksum and it will be correct for you, but actually you will use fake DLL which already loaded in memory.
For protect you may use algorithm:

1. Do not use static DLL linkage. Load DLL manually using LoadLibraryEx without calling DllMain with flag LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE
2. Verify checksum of DLL code **in memory**, not in the file. If checksum is not valid, do not do next steps
3. Load all DLL dependencies and call DllMain manually <-- this is most complicated step, so you need to resolve all DLL refs by hands
4. Load required DLL functions using GetProcAddress or by parsing DLL export table manually, and use them
   Of course, this can not avoid checksum verification and it is complicated way, but you can prevent most of simple attack methods.
   Depends on deep of implementation step #3, some of DLLs will not work, if you didn't implement thread local storage (TLS) calls